# Ef Core Query to get users who have multiple events that occur per DayId

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

So I have a table called Events with UserId, DayId & Event and I'd like to with the help of a query fetch the users who have multiple Events per DayId. However, I'm unsure on how to do that.

This is an example of what I'd like to fetch.

UserId,   DayId,  Event 
20,       1,      "Football" 
20,       1,      "Basket"

I was thinking of something like this:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
var multipleEventsPerDayQuery = from p in _context.Events group p by new { p.UserId, p.DayId, p.Event } into g where g.Count() > 1 select new { g.Key.UserId, g.Key.DayId, g.Key.Event };

var multipleEventsPerDayList = await multipleEventsPerDayQuery.ToListAsync();

//GetUsersById is a method I already have
foreach (var u in multipleEventsPerDayList) {
users.Add(await GetUsersById(u.UserId));
}
```

But obviously the query is wrong and I just can't seem to wrap my head around how I'm supposed to write the query to get what I want.

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: Found the solution, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I realise now that I shouldn't have grouped by p.Event as well.
It should be:

```
var multipleEventsPerDayQuery = from p in _context.Events group p by new { p.UserId, p.DayId} into g where g.Count() > 1 select new { g.Key.UserId, g.Key.DayId };
```

This solved the problem as far as I can see.